# How can i get an output from encryption algorithm which equals to the input (Bypass encryption)

Tags: java, cryptography

I'm using java to make multiple-algorithm cryptographic program to encrypte given data depending on given key and algorithm chosen by user, Algorithms include :
1-"no-encryption" which should output the input data as it is without encryption.
2-"AES"
3-"Blowfish"
4-"RC2"
.
.
.....
How can i use the following function to be valid even for the first choice (i.e no-encryption).

```
public static String encode(String strs,String key_plain, String algorithm) {
byte[] key=key_plain.getBytes();

c=Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
SecretKeySpec k = new SecretKeySpec(key, algorithm);       
c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, k);
byte[] enc_out=c.doFinal(strs.getBytes());
String output=Arrays.toString(enc_out).replace(" ","").replace("{","").replace("}","");
return output;
}
```

I appreciate your time to help me

Comment: Note that your output method of removing all characters that distinguish one byte from the other may not be easy to revert. Also note that you should indicate a mode of encryption and padding method together with the block cipher.

Comment: Thanks owlstead, 1-removing these characters helps in decoding them when retreiving from a database.

Comment: 2-i intend to use ECB mode with no IV because encryption and decryption are not synchronized

Comment: ECB mode is not safe for strings. With regards to the string, you should encode as base 64 instead. How do you know if the amount of digits in the output is 2 or 3 for each character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple return the string if no encryption desired?

```
public static String encode(String strs,String key_plain, String algorithm) {
   if (algorithm.equals("no-encryption")){ //maybe use an enum?
      return strs;
   }
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the [`NullCipher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/NullCipher.html) which extends `Cipher`.